# Angular 9 component library references

Tags: angular, typescript, npm

I have a component library with several projects that will be reused across multiple applications. In my component library:

- `component-a`
- `component-b`
- `component-c` (references `component-a`)
- `component-d` (references `component-a` and `component-b`)

In an external application, I have `module-1` that references `component-d`, but when I compile the external application, I get errors saying that `component-d` cannot find `component-a` or `component-b`, even though they are installed alongside them.

I've extensively explored `npm link`, `npm install`, and tsconfig path mappings, but I have yet to find a winning combination that allows the external application to compile.

What's the proper way to create a component library where the components contained within it reference one another and can be consumed by an external application?

**NOTE: I have made sure in the component library that I am building the components without ivy, and the paths I've mapped to the adjacent component is using the dist/component-d compiled code.**

**NOTE: I would include copied entries from my `package.json` and `tsconfig.ts/tsconfig.lib.ts` files, but I am limited in what I can share unredacted. If you need more information to help get me moving that I will see if I can make it generic enough to comply with company policy.**

Thanks in advance, I'm pretty frustrated at the moment. I appreciate any guidance.

EDIT: I have set up a generic, scaled-down example of my structure: https://github.com/xamlzealot/angular-ivy-guq4na. It doesn't seem very helpful, but I also connected it to StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-guq4na.

The main takeaway is that `shared-components` lib needs to reference `design-system`. `AwesomeApp` needs to ref BOTH `design-system` and `shared-components`. NGC seems to not like lib referencing lib, I'm hoping I'm missing something here, or there's perhaps a workaround.

Comment: In your component library, are all your components-[a to d] declared in a module? If that's the case you'll import that module in module-1 and it would normally be enough. If not can you share how you're importing your component-d in your module-1?

Comment: Please see edit to OP. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for providing the repository and the stackblitz, after reviewing your configuration, it looks like you don't have the right configuration for your library's paths in the main tsconfig.json that's why your imports are not recognized.

in your **./tsconfig.json** replace this :

```
    "paths": {
      "shared-components": [
        "dist/shared-components/shared-components",
        "dist/shared-components"
      ],
      "design-system": [
        "dist/design-system/design-system",
        "dist/design-system"
      ]
    }
```

By this :

```
    "paths": {
      "shared-components": [
        "projects/shared-components/src/public-api.ts"
      ],
      "design-system": [
        "projects/design-system/src/public-api.ts"
      ]
    }
```

May I suggest that in the future if you are going the route of a **monorepo** for your libraries and applications to use Nx https://nx.dev/angular it's a very useful tool to manage all your libraries and applications at the same place giving you access to a powerful CLI which will mitigate this kind of issues.